# How to use iFrame to match URL in separate domains

Tags: javascript, php, multiple-domains

I have two websites. Domain.com and DomainTwo.com

Domain.com hosts all of the content and DomainTwo.com mirrors that content using a simple iFrame.

What I'd like to do is make it so if I link to "DomainTwo.com/folder/samplefile.jpg", the iFrame matches the URL and creates an iFrame for Domain.com/folder/sampelfile.jpg.

In other words, you wouldn't be able to tell DomainTwo.com is actually iframing anything unless you viewed the source code of the page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried plopping the URI in your iframe `src`?

```
<iframe src ="http://Domain.com<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

in javascript it would be something like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src = "http://domain.com" + location.pathname;
```

Of course clinking inside the iframe will not update the url. You'd probably be better of using wildcard domain, domain mapping, or whatever that's called.